# PHP timeout on put/get/list commands

Tags: php, ftp, passive-mode

I've been dealing with this problem all day long. [A couple hours ago I wrote this Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/702691/php-ftp-pasv-mode-on-centos-7). I've got a PHP script that works OK in my development PC but on the real server are not quite good.

The script is:

```
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server); 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

//$DB = @mysqli_connect($hostname_DB,$username_DB,$password_DB,$database_DB); 

if ($login_result == null)
    die("Cannot connect");   
echo "Connected<br />Changing to passive mode <br />"; 

if (ftp_pasv($conn_id, true)) 
{
    echo "Passive mode: ON<br /><br />";
}
else
{
    echo "Passive mode: OFF<br /><br />";
}


echo "Current dir: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";

if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, "ABC")) {
    echo "Current dir is now: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";
} else { 
    echo "Dir was not changed\n";
}

$files = array();
$files = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, '.'); 
echo "<br />Files<br />";
print_r($files);

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

On this line: `$files = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, '.'); (line 65)` the script freezes about a minute or so and gives this error:

```
Connected
Changing to passive mode 
Passive mode: ON

Current dir: / Current dir is now: /ABC
Warning: ftp_rawlist(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115) in /var/www/html/ftpscript.php on line 65

Files
```

Without changing into passive mode is the same output without the warning. No files are echoed either (below 'Files'). The same happend with any command like nlist, mput, mget, etc.

I read [this article](http://www.elitehosts.com/blog/php-ftp-passive-ftp-server-behind-nat-nightmare/) but didn't know if it still applies. Others sites says is my firewall configuration but I don't understand what to do. My server is running:

```
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2014 12:59:36) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

I opened ports 20, 21 and range from 5000 to 5100. With all these I don't know if is a problem of my end but PHP. If I use lftp (cli ftp client) it works OK.

**EDIT #1**

It seems it's a bug in the ftp implementation in php. However I don't know how to apply the patch listed here https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug_id=55651&patch=ftp_usepasvaddress.patch&revision=latest

Please, any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended writing function to download/upload and listing using curl with PHP. AFAIK It's a PHP bug when using the built-in ftp implementation. Curl is a bit slower but it's ok for my needs.